# list comprehension creating nested lists

Tags: python, nested, list-comprehension

I'd like to create nested lists of days per month list per year list:

```
[[ 31, 29, 31, 30 ], [ 31, 28, 31, 30 ] ]
```

with

```
mm = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
yy = [ 2012, 2013 ]
```

but my code:

```
[ [ result.append( calendar.monthrange( y, m )[ 1 ] ) for m in mm] for y in yy ]
```

produces:

```
[31, 29, 31, 30,  31, 28, 31, 30 ]
```

Can someone please tell me what I've done wrong?  Thanks.  BSL

Comment: Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39935226/13762264)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I'm assuming the full code looks something like this:

```
result = []
[ [ result.append( calendar.monthrange( y, m )[ 1 ] ) for m in mm] for y in yy ]   
print(result)
```

The problem with your code is your understanding of list comprehension. List comprehension creates a list, so you shouldn't be appending anything to another list within that. Right now, you are only appending things to result and then printing result and now actually creating a list from the list comprehension.

Here is the equivalent of what you are doing right now:

```
result  = [ ]
for y in yy:
    for m in mm:
        result.append( calendar.monthrange( y, m )[ 1 ] )
```

Here is the equivalent of what you want to be doing:

```
result  = [ ]
for y in yy:
    year = []
    for m in mm:
        year.append( calendar.monthrange( y, m )[ 1 ] )
    result.append(year)
```

And here is the list comprehension version of that:

```
>>> result = [[calendar.monthrange( y, m )[ 1 ] for m in mm] for y in yy]
>>> print(result)

[[31, 29, 31, 30], [31, 28, 31, 30]]
```

Comment: Thanks very much, Hayley.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: Glad I could help, if this answered your question feel free to accept the answer by pressing on the check mark :)