# Get two lists out of one list using one line list comprehension in Python

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have one list containing True and False values.  Using list comprehension, out of this list, 
I can get two separate lists where one has only True values and the other one has only False 
values as under:

```
aList  = [True, False, False, True, False, True, True]
trues  = [ x for x in aList if x==True ]
falses = [ x for x in aList if x==False ]

print(trues)  # [True, True, True, True]
print(falses) # [False, False, False]
```

Is it possible to get two separate lists out of one list using list comprehension in one line? Something like:

```
trues, falses = [ [a,b] for x in aList a=True if x else b=False]
```

Here, I get the error: "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" mentioning caret just below 'True'
of a=True

Comment: No, a list comprehension always results in *one* list. However, you can use *nested* list comprehensions where you get one list containing two other lists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [list comprehension creating nested lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36037922/list-comprehension-creating-nested-lists)

Comment: If you want to get multiple lists with a oneliner and avoid nesting you should use a dictionary comprehension to build a dictionary with your lists as values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more or less the same that you have but compressed in one line:

```
aList  = [True, False, False, True, False, True, True]
trues,falses  = [x for x in aList if x], [x for x in aList if not x]
```

This way you'll get two lists. If you enclose it in brackets, you'll get one list.

Comment: Thanks, for so prompt reply.  For me, your reply has opened new dimention of Python programming.  To be specific, since I am a new programmer in Python, I came to know a simple logic that a statement -> trues, falses = [ code .. ], [ code .. ] will create two separate lists from one list.  Thanks, once again.

Comment: @NizamuddinShaikh--just to clarify the right-side expression is actually using two (2) lists comprehensions, not one.  The right-side is creating a tuple from these two lists comprehensions.  The left-side is then unpacking this tuple into trues & falses.